# publish Database project to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, publish, database-project

I have a large database project and I am trying to publish it to Azure. I have done the following:

- In the project settings, changed Target Platform to Windows Azure
- On Azure Made sure I am on Standard tier S0
- Made sure the Server Version is V12
- Changed the Timeout for the publish
- Tried creating a new SQL Server database

All result in a ton of errors a couple of which are:

- ForeignKey: [xxxxxx] has an unresolved reference
- ROWGUIDCOL is not supported for the targeted platform

I tried searching and tried everything I saw with no luck. Also, I need to be able to publish as things change, so using the migration tool is not an option.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please tell us which tool and version you are using and facing this issue? SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) should be able to handle your scenario. You can download the latest version of SSDT from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Eric

That was correct. I just needed to update my SSDT. I posted this as the answer before, but it never showed up.

Thank you